# value not saving in the form when dynamically creating an input

Tags: jquery, post-meta, forms

```
var AppendDivStore = jQuery(".AppendDivStore");
jQuery('<input />').attr(
    { type: 'text', class: 'PastetheSkillsValuemy'+inc+'', id: 'wpjobus_resume_skills['+inc+'][1]', name: 'wpjobus_resume_skills['+inc+'][1]', value: '20%'}
).appendTo(AppendDivStore);
```

[image: pic]

okay when I created an input dynamically, its value is not saving in the backend. why is it so?

*function.php*

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'wpjobus_resume_skills', $_POST['wpjobus_resume_skills']);
```

*form:*

```
<form id="wpjobus-add-resume" type="post" action="" >
```

*submit button:*

```
<input style="margin-bottom: 0;" name="submit" type="submit" value="<?php global $redux_demo, $recipe_state; $recipe_state = $redux_demo['resume-state']; if($recipe_state == "1" or current_user_can('administrator')) { _e( 'Update Resume', 'agrg' ); } else { _e( 'Update Resume For Review', 'agrg' ) ;} ?>" class="input-submit">
```

*submit:*

```
submitHandler: function(form) {

    tinyMCE.triggerSave();

    jQuery('#wpjobus-add-resume .input-submit').css('display','none');

    jQuery('#wpjobus-add-resume .submit-loading').css('display','block');

    jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({

        type: "POST",

        data: jQuery(form).serialize(),

        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', 

        success: function(data) {

            if(data != 0) {

                jQuery('#wpjobus-add-resume .submit-loading').css('display','none');

                jQuery('#success').fadeIn();

                <?php $redirect_link = home_url()."/my-account"; ?>

                var delay = 5;

                setTimeout(function(){ window.location = '<?php echo $redirect_link; ?>';}, delay);

            } else {

                jQuery('#wpjobus-add-resume .input-submit').css('display','block');

                jQuery('#wpjobus-add-resume .submit-loading').css('display','none');

                jQuery('#error').fadeIn();

            }

        },

        error: function(data) {

            jQuery('#wpjobus-add-resume .input-submit').css('display','block');

            jQuery('#wpjobus-add-resume .submit-loading').css('display','none');

            jQuery('#error').fadeIn();

        }

    });
```

Comment: Where's your HTML `<form method="POST">`, and the `submit` button? Are you sure, you are getting data with `$_POST['wpjobus_resume_skills']`?

Comment: yeah i am saving many other data too. the problem is when i creted an input dynamically.

Comment: Shouldn't this: `<form id="wpjobus-add-resume" type="post" action="" >`.... be this: `<form id="wpjobus-add-resume" method="post" action="" >`?  What is a form type?